# mvnw.cmd for demo spring-boot project not working in windows

Tags: spring-boot, spring-initializr, maven-wrapper

I generated a simple demo project (`2.3.0` version) from Spring Initializr to my windows `8.1` OS and below is the basic structure

```
C:.
└───src
    ├───main
    │   ├───java
    │   │   └───com
    │   │       └───example
    │   │           └───demo
    │   └───resources
    └───test
        └───java
            └───com
                └───example
                    └───demo
```

I tried running `mvnw.cmd clean` and getting bellow error:

```
C:\Users\Downloads\demo\demo>mvnw.cmd clean
"}" was unexpected at this time.
```

Below is the same output in powershell

```
PS C:\Users\Downloads\demo\demo> .\mvnw.cmd clean
"}" was unexpected at this time.
PS C:\Users\Downloads\demo\demo>
```

I see the issue is occurring in following lines within `mvnw.cmd` file :

```
powershell -Command "&{"^
    "$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient;"^
    "if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty('%MVNW_USERNAME%') -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty('%MVNW_PASSWORD%'))) {"^
    "$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential('%MVNW_USERNAME%', '%MVNW_PASSWORD%');"^
    "}"^
    "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; $webclient.DownloadFile('%DOWNLOAD_URL%', '%WRAPPER_JAR%')"^
    "}"
```

Not sure if i am missing anything.

Comment: Did you run this in `cmd` or `powershell`? Try to run it in powershell

Comment: yes i tried in `cmd` and `powershell` and was getting the same error

Comment: Try to use a different  version of mvnw

Comment: @Sachin did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @ValentinDespa Not yet but strangely i see this issue only on my machine. I did try the same in another machine and worked fine.

Comment: I have this error only in the Jenkins workspace folder. I have opened a bug report here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MWRAPPER/issues/MWRAPPER-4

Comment: issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWRAPPER-48 opened: please contact us here

Comment: Happens to me with Maven 3.8.4, generated wrapper with 3.1.0 version. 
```
Edition Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 20H2
Installed on ‎2/‎28/‎2022
OS build 19042.1526
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, error in both cmd and powershell. Simply copying the project to an alternative directory solved the problem.

Im on windows 10, the project was originally in my downloads directory. I moved this into documents.

Answer (score 0):

Testes and i worked on this path: C:\tmp\New (2){6} folder\my-app57(2). The problem is the ')' character.

My solution is:

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    powershell -Command "&{"^
          "$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient;"^
          "if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty('%MVNW_USERNAME%') -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty('%MVNW_PASSWORD%'))) {"^
          "$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential('%MVNW_USERNAME%', '%MVNW_PASSWORD%');"^
          "}"^
          "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; $webclient.DownloadFile('%DOWNLOAD_URL%', '!WRAPPER_JAR!')"^
          "}"
@endlocal
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWRAPPER-76